# Python: finding all tuples with constrained elements that add up to a constant

Tags: python, vector, iteration, combinations

Suppose I'm given an vector of length 4 with minimum values (0,0,0,0) and maximum values (2,1,3,2). I would like to find all integer vectors in this range that add up to, say, 5.

The following code achieves that:

```
maxvalues = (2,1,3,2)
k = 5
t = []
for x1 in range(maxvalues[0]+1):
    for x2 in range(maxvalues[1]+1):
        for x3 in range(maxvalues[2]+1):
             for x4 in range(maxvalues[3]+1):
                  if x1+x2+x3+x4 is k:
                      t.append((x1,x2,x3,x4))
```

However, this code does not generalize very well to larger vectors and seems a bit inefficient. Does anyone have a good way to generalize this?

Edit: slight mistake, forgot the if-statement

Comment: You're almost there. Just find a way to make it a recursive search and you will have generalised it!

Comment: As a side note. Don't use `is` for equality tests. There's no harm with numbers. But if you get used to it it may bite you when you use other objects.

Comment: Even bigger numbers which are equal may not be identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product

for x1, x2, x3, x4 in product(*(range(i+1) for i in maxvalues)):
    t.append((x1, x2, x3, x4))
```

Although much better (and more general) would be converting the `product` object into a list directly.

```
t = list(product(*(range(i+1) for i in maxvalues)))
```

With the `if` statement included, it would look something like this.

```
t = [i for i in product(*(range(i+1) for i in maxvalues)) if sum(i) == k]
```

Comment: +1. Beat me by a nano second. Although you could just construct the list from the iterable.

Comment: That helps. However, I'd still have to manually write down n variables. Is it possible to iterate over a single tuple x?

Comment: @Forzaa I was just up to that part

Comment: I accidentally left out an if-statement in my initial code btw.

Comment: Great answer.  I was going to post a competing one, but I just can't!  So here's a tip: if you say `range(min(k,i)+1)` instead of `range(i+1)`, you will achieve a massive speedup when k is small relative to maxvalues, by pruning the solution space early.